# How can I create a structured report in Word based on data from an Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm assuming that the answer to this question will involve some VBA, hence why I'm asking it here -- please let me know if I should ask my question somewhere else.

I have to prepare frequent reports that include a list of recommendations for clients. The documents are presented in Word documents. Each recommendation in a report has the following format:

```
[Name of recommendation] ([Product code])

[Multiple-line description of recommendation]
```

The "Name/Product code" line has a heading style applied to it, and the description has the Normal style applied to it.

In my Excel file I can create a table that includes all of my recommendations:

```
Name1 ..... Code1 ..... Description1

Name2 ..... Code2 ..... Description2

.....

NameN ... CodeN ..... DescriptionN
```

I could then merge all of this information together in Excel, and pass it through to Word via a mail merge, but I don't seem to be able to do that in a way that creates the heading styles that I want. I'm assuming I'll need to do some VBA work to achieve what I want, but I've never used VBA before. What's the basic idea I need to work with here?

Comment: _Microsoft documentation:_

> [How to use the Mail Merge feature in Word to create and to print form letters that use the data from an Excel worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-mail-merge-feature-in-word-to-create-and-to-print-form-letters-that-use-the-data-from-an-excel-worksheet-d8709e29-c106-2348-7e38-13eecc338679?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Simple mail merge with a suitably prepared primary merge document should do it. No vba needed. The styling gets done in Word, not Excel. Note, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word

Comment: Thanks both. The reason I asked here is that no mail merge documentation I've been able to find has given me a solution (it doesn't seem to be able to iterate over a series of Excel fields -- it needs to know in advance how many fields there are), hence why I asked here as I'm assuming I'll need to use VBA. I've asked in the Microsoft Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following advice in a comment above I asked on the Microsoft Community about doing this as a straightforward mail merge. I've been advised there that what I want to do isn't possible with a mail merge, and will instead required some VBA.

I don't have any experience with VBA, but ChatGPT was able to provide me with the following, which seems like a sensible approach (posted here in case anyone else hits this limitation with mail merge):

```html
Sub SimpleMailMerge()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Create an instance of Word
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If wdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    
    'Path to your Word document template
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\to\your\Word\Template.docx")
    
    'Set your Excel sheet
    Set ExcelSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    
    'Find the last row with data in column A
    LastRow = ExcelSheet.Cells(ExcelSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Loop through each row in Excel
    For i = 2 To LastRow 'assuming row 1 contains headers
        'Add Heading with style "Heading 3"
        wdDoc.Paragraphs.Add.Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3")
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text = ExcelSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        'Add Body with style "Normal"
        wdDoc.Paragraphs.Add.Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text = ExcelSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
        
        'Insert a paragraph break between entries
        wdDoc.Paragraphs.Add
    Next i
    
    'Show Word application
    wdApp.Visible = True
    
    'Close Excel without saving changes (optional)
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```